# Emacs: How can I delete all hyphenations at the end of lines in a text?

Tags: emacs, regex

I scanned a pdf with usuall hyphenation at the end of the lines and need to process the text.

Example:

```
There are these two young fish swim-
ming along and they happen to meet 
an older fish swimming the other 
way, who nods at them and says "Mor-
ning, boys".
```

What I'd like to get by some regex-magic is obvious:

```
There are these two young fish swimming along and they happen to meet an older fish swimming the other way, who nods at them and says "Morning, boys".
```

I tried `\([a-z]\)-$^\([a-z]\)` , but that did not give any result.

Comment: Are you on Linux? Will a sed or perl solution do?

Comment: @terdon I solved my problem, see below, but yes, I'm on Linux and sed or perl were welcome.

Comment: Glad you solved it, please accept your answer, it gives you rep and reduces the unanswered questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. The trick is to insert a second line into the search regexp. This is done by typing C-q C-j on the search side. So what I typed was:

```
\([a-z]\)- C-q C-j \([a-z]\)
```

without any SPC before the C-q C-j, which resulted the minibuffer looking like this:

```
\([a-z]\)-
\([a-z]\)
```